# Could not load file or assembly Microsoft.Data.SqlClient, Version=5.0.0.0

Tags: c#, azure-web-app-service, .net-6.0, nuget-package, sqlclient

Facing following issue after deploying app to azure app service:

> Unhandled exception. System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load
> file or assembly 'Microsoft.Data.SqlClient, Version=5.0.0.0,
> Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=***********'. The system cannot find
> the file specified.

Locally everything works as fine.
**Microsoft.Data.SqlClient** presented in **site/wwwroot**

[image: site/wwwroot]

Runtime Stack: Dotnetcore - 6.0
Main app and all class libs on .net6
Server Operating System: Linux

Microsoft.Data.SqlClient presented as reference from Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer (v.7.0.2)

Tried different kinds of Nuget Packages versions - still have same issue
Tried to install Microsoft.Data.SqlClient (latest version & 5.0.0.0) directly into projects - still the same

Comment: You say you are using dotnetcore6 but it is looking for a .net 5 assembly. Could this be the issue? If you want to you could install the runtime and sdk 5 but thats just kicking the can down the road. Try to look in the solution file or csproj and see it is looking for dotnet5 anywhere.

Comment: Just realized that the 5.0.0.0 might refer to the assembly version and not dotnet version.\

Comment: 5.0.0.0 - version of required Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.dll i think

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue. Things I've tried that have not resolved the issue:  
- In case the DLL was built for the wrong platform, tried publishing with a platform specified `dotnet publish - publish --os linux`
- Used CLI tool to list the metadata of the DLL - it's definitely assembly version 5.0.0.0 and the public token matches
- Tried scorched earth - cleared nuget cache / git clean -xfd / deleted and recreated the app service
- Tried adding an explicit dependency on Microsoft.Data.SqlClient

No love.

Answer (score 3):

### Solution

For Azure App Services running the `kind: linux`, the `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` will not work with the default `linux-x64` Runtime Identifier. You must specify the more specific RID `debian-x64`.

`dotnet publish -r debian-x64`

### Supporting Background Knowledge

There can be multiple root causes for this issue, but based on your specific scenario (specifically Microsoft.Data.SqlClient 5.0.0.0 on linux app service), your build target is likely wrong.

The key concept here is the Runtime Identifier, which specifies what environment the built application will run in.

`dotnet publish` by default will build for the environment in which the command was run. So if your build pipeline is running linux, it will likely use an RID like `linux-x64`.

You can override this in two ways. You can set the os flag, which will set the RID under the hood to `linux-x64`

`dotnet publish --os linux`

Alternatively, you can set the RID manually like this:

`dotnet publish -r linux-x64`

This will work for most scenarios, as most dotnet DLLs will be cross-compatible between many distributions of linux. However `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` needs more specific runtime targeting to function correctly.

Linux based Azure App Services run Debian. And so we need to set the more specific rid `debian-x64`.

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me in .Net 8.0 when I had several versions of microsoft.data.sqlclient in C:/Users/username/.nuget/packages/microsoft.data.sqlclient.

Fix: In VS2022, Package Manager, uninstall all references to microsoft.data.sqlclient.

Delete microsoft.data.sqlclient in the nuget folder.

Reinstall 5.1.2 with package manager.

Finally: Make **sure** that the RUNTIMES folder is copied to the final executable folder.

Comment: I totally forgot to bring the RUNTIMES folder over.  This fixed the issue.

Answer (score -1):

The solution for us was to:

1. Locate the actual DLL file (Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.dll) on the developer's desktop filesystem (easy to find; once you're referenced it using NuGet it gets copied to multiple places)
2. Add it to the web project (we placed it right in the root)
3. Mark it (via Properties tool window) as Copy Always

Step 3 results in our .csproj file looks like this:

```
<ItemGroup>
   <None Update="Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.dll">        
     <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
   </None>
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: Checked, still facing the same error